# some data is not being stored in the array

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am working on this code which splits chemical equations into compounds, and then splits them into elements and the number of their atom. However, for some reason, the last elements of each compound are not getting stored in the array.

```py
class compound(object):  # A class of compounds. It stores all the relevant data for the compound
    def __init__(self, n_compound):
        self.n_compound = n_compound
        self.f_compound = str(n_compound)
        temp = ""
        e = ""
        v = "0"
        self.element = []
        self.val = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.f_compound)-1):
            if self.f_compound[i].isalpha() and self.f_compound[i+1].isupper():
                temp += self.f_compound[i] + "1"
            else:
                temp += self.f_compound[i]
        temp += self.f_compound[len(self.f_compound) - 1]
        if temp[len(temp)-1].isalpha():
            temp += "1"
        self.f_compound = temp
        ########issue is appearing in the code here
        for i in range(0, len(self.f_compound)):
            if self.f_compound[i].isalpha():
                if v != "0":
                    self.element.append(str(e))
                    self.val.append(int(v))
                    e = self.f_compound[i]
                    v = "0"
                    i -= 1
                else:
                    e += self.f_compound[i]
            elif self.f_compound[i].isdigit():
                v += self.f_compound[i]
        ########This block of code Is not working properly 
        print(self.n_compound)
        for x in range(0, len(self.element)):
            print(self.element[x] + ": " + str(self.val[x]))
        print(".............................................")



equation = str('Cu + HNO3 -> CuN2O6 + H2O + NO')
#str(input("Enter chemical equation: "))
equation = equation.replace("->", "+").replace(' ', '')
compounds = []  # An array of compounds

for i in range(0, len(equation.split("+"))):
     # Assigning a compound name to an object of the compound class and storing it in the array
    compounds.append(compound(equation.split("+")[i]))
```

I am getting this output:

Cu  
.............................................  
HNO3 
H: 1
N: 1
.............................................
CuN2O6
Cu: 1
N: 2
.............................................
H2O
H: 2
.............................................
NO
N: 1
.............................................

However, the correct output should be this:

Cu  
Cu: 1
.............................................  
HNO3 
H: 1
N: 1
O: 3
.............................................
CuN2O6
Cu: 1
N: 2
O: 6
.............................................
H2O
H: 2
O: 1
.............................................
NO
N: 1
O: 1
.............................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last element is not displayed, this means you have to look if the `for` loop excludes it, or just doesn't handle the result after the last iteration.

In this case, i think you only have to append the last element and its valence after the loop ends :

```
for i in range(0, len(self.f_compound)):
    if self.f_compound[i].isalpha():
        if v != "0":
            self.element.append(str(e))
            self.val.append(int(v))
            e = self.f_compound[i]
            v = "0"
            i -= 1
        else:
            e += self.f_compound[i]
    elif self.f_compound[i].isdigit():
        v += self.f_compound[i]
# Fix :
self.element.append(str(e))     
self.val.append(int(v))
```

---

Result :

```
Cu
Cu: 1
.............................................
HNO3
H: 1
N: 1
O: 3
.............................................
CuN2O6
Cu: 1
N: 2
O: 6
.............................................
H2O
H: 2
O: 1
.............................................
NO
N: 1
O: 1
.............................................
```